# customize JMenuBar (e.g. BackgroundImage, highlighting color,...)

Tags: java, swing, customization, menu, menubar

I'd like to adapt/customize the appearance of my JMenuBar, so i do a little research. Now i wondering why there are so little information about this issue?!

I just found one good source here: http://forums.sun.com thread.jspa?messageID=4457769#4457769 which allows me to use a BackgroundImage for the MenuBar. The drawback is that i have to create such things like rollover effect (highlight BackgroundColor of JMenuItems), calculation of the jmenu positions by myself.

Did anyone of you knows a better, easier way to approach my goal? All i'd like to do is to customize the background of the JMenuBar by displaying a image instead of a plain color. Further the rollover-Effekts and the normal behaviour of a menu should be obtained.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this for jmenu positioning:

```
menuBar.setLayout(null);
openMenu.setBounds(pos_x,pos_y,width,height);
menuBar.add(openMenu);
```

I am also trying to change the background color,but still didnt find any way. :(

Answer (score 0):

here is [another thread in the sun forums](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?forumID=57&threadID=783238) that show something similar to what you are trying:  the developer overrides the `paintComponent()` method on the `JMenuBar` to draw an image.